# Me inserta la hora 3 horas adelantada

Tags: java, mysql, insert

Tengo un java.util.Date, que tiene una hora en particular(no la actual), y cuando inserto ese Date en mi base de datos, me muestra la hora 3 horas adelantada, en la base de datos tengo un campo de tipo DATETIME que me guarda la hora, este es mi código:

Desde aquí capturo la fecha y hora que ingrese el usuario:

```
String[] tiempo = jTextField4.getText().split(":");
        String hora = tiempo[0];
        String minutos = tiempo[1];

        Date fecha = jDateChooser1.getDate();//Obtenemos el Date
        fecha.setHours(Integer.parseInt(hora));
        fecha.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(minutos));
```

Luego desde otro método que me pide un parámetro ejecuto la sentencia SQL:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reserva (nombre, dni, fecha, id_mesa, vigente) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 1)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setString(1, reserva.getNombre());
            ps.setLong(2, reserva.getDni());
            ps.setObject(3, reserva.getFecha());
            ps.setInt(4, reserva.getMesa().getId());
ps.execute();
            ps.close();
```

Cuando imprimo el Date por consola me devuelva la hora perfectamente, pero cuando lo inserto en la base de datos me da 3 horas adelantadas.
Que puede estar pasando? por que no me muestra la hora que quiero?

Un saludo y gracias desde ya.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84996/discussion-on-question-by-pablo-palma-me-inserta-la-hora-3-horas-adelantada).

Comment: ¿La hora grabada en la base de datos la consultas con la misma aplicación o la vea adelantada desde el MySQL Workbench u otra aplicación?

Comment: MySQL guarda la hora en zona horaria UTC (o GMT, o Zulu, o +00:00) y vos debes estar en GMT-3. Si en tu programa tenés la zona horaria bien configurada no tendrías que tener problema.